# Node Webkit window hide toolbar dynamically in js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, webkit, node-webkit

Is there a way to toggle the default toolbar in a nodewebkit app using js ?

My app shouldn't display the toolbar as it's set in the `package.json` and it works fine in most cases. But for some reasons, in an embedded windows xp distribution it display's the toolbar anyway..

So I would like to try to hide it dynamically after the app is launched.

And I don't find any window functions to do that in the [documentation](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki).

Any ideas ?

Comment: I could not fin it too. But you can make inspector and reload in top menu with shortcut  `gui.Window.get().reloadDev();` and `gui.Window.get().showDevTools();`

Comment: I've tried that, but it isn't working either..

Comment: Does it show any error? Did you try like this `var gui = require('nw.gui'); gui.Window.get().showDevTools();`?

Comment: Based on my digging I have also concluded that its not possible. However, one solution is to create your own toolbar that you can show and hide dynamically. I believe all the functionality in the OOTB toolbar can be emulated by using documented nw API's.

Comment: @PavelEvstigneev Yes this is the best solution I found so far, but it requires to add a startup file, to open the index.html in a new window.

Comment: @benuuts, for me it working simple, I just put `index.html` in package.json: https://github.com/Paxa/postbird/blob/master/package.json

Comment: Yes it works in most cases but on this device my app started with the default toolbar shown, so I had to run a pre-script to open index.html in a new window.